# How to do equivalent of Flask Safe in ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, flask

I cannot seem to replicate the equivalent functions in my Ajax call as I can in regular Javascript on my main HTML page. I am using Python/Flask as the back-end. Is there a similar way to use the {{ variable | safe }} syntax in AJAX to get similar results?

My sample.py class

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.product = 'something'
    def transfer_to_js(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)
```

My flask function

```
@app.route('/get_data')
def get_data():
    sample = Sample()
    sample_str = sample.transfer_to_js()
    return jsonify(result=sample_str)
```

HTML/js (where I achieve the desired results)

```
<script>
    console.log({{ result|safe }});
    <!-- returns {product:"Something"} -->
</script>
```

My AJAX call (where I fail to achieve the desired results)

```
$.getJSON('/get_data', {}, 
    function(data) {
        console.log(data.result); // returns {"product":"Something"}
```

Call that utilizes this result

```
function printObject(obj){
    console.log(obj['product']); // prints "Something" for regular JS call, prints undefined for AJAX call
}
```

Thus, I believe the difference is subtle, i.e. quotes vs lack of quotes in the dictionary key, but its enough to cause the printObject function to fail. Is there a way to deal with this outside of the python function (as I intend to call this function both from the regular js function as well as the AJAX call)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in the AJAX call, the result is being passed back as a string and not a JSON object, therefore, to convert it, I wrote this

```
$.getJSON('/get_data', {}, 
    function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.result)); 
    }
```

and my results were as expected